# Setting ListAdapter after Task completes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter, listadapter

In my code I do something like this

```
// Start AsyncTask - And load Network data into an Object
// Set ListAdapter with Object from Task.
```

However, The `Task` never completes before the `ListAdapter` tries to be set, so it is `null`.

Setting the adapter in the `onPostExecute` is not an option because this `Task` is its own class and is used in other areas.

I think the main problem here is the `Async` part of `Task`.  Is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: onPostExecute is the only better option for you. But I guess you have already tried that

Comment: Why can't you send the `ListAdapter` and `Context` to a constructor of the class then update it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @codeMagic  Well, I use the `Task` in a different `Activity` and I do a bit more than just `setAdapter`... some of the other things I am doing are Fragment-specific... If you guys are saying this is the only option I can try to move things around I guess.

Comment: There's always more options, I'm just trying to think of the easiest in this case. I understand it is used for other things but you can have a separate constructor for `Activitites` with lists so it doesn't effect others. However, if it is much different than what other `Activities` use it for then you may be better off using a separate `AsyncTask` as an inner class of this `Activity`

Comment: @codeMagic  I agree on the inner task.  I was simply trying to reduce duplicate code.  I do like the separate constructor idea.

Comment: I understand that. Reducing code is great but sometimes you have to consider which way will actually save on headaches. Separate constructors could definitely work but I don't know what you so beyond that. It may just take a little extra effort to check for `null`s in your `Async` but might be worth it

Comment: You can pass in a callback and execute the callback in onPostExecute.

Comment: @codeMagic  Why don't you put answer as adding a new constructor.  That worked out.  I simply had a second constructor that passed `context` and `boolean` and set `boolean` true.  `ListAdapter` was only set if that `boolean` was true.  So it wouldn't affect other instances.

Comment: @KickingLettuce posted answer. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments to answer

You can create a `constructor` in your `AsyncTask` that will take whatever `params` you need from this `Activity` for instance a `Context` and a `ListAdapter` or `boolean` as you chose.
Then when you create an instance of the `AsyncTask` you can pass in these `params`

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(MainActivity.this, booleanVar);  // passing Context and boolean
myTask.execute();
```

Then in your `AsyncTask` you can check if a certain variable is `null` or check for `boolean` value to decide what to do in `onPostExecute()`

Then you can have a `constructor` that deals with a different set of `params` for the other `Activities` that need to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can create a listener interface and make your activity implement that interface.
When the asyntask is complete i.e in onPostExecute call the method of the interface and activity will receive the callback if registered.

Answer (score 0):

Always set ListView's adapter immediately after ListView creation (typically, in onCreate or onCreateView, depending on your layouts).

The **contents** of the adapter is a different matter. You can (and should) make your adapter initially empty, and add actual data to it only on AsyncTask completion e.g. in onPostExecute.  After that, also in onPostExecute, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to display Objects.